# Firebase disable session_start event ANDROID

Tags: android, firebase

I see the event in firebase console but nowhere in the code add it, is this event added by default? Can I remove it? 
[My firebase console Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FIMIs.png)

## Code

```
`private FirebaseAnalytics mFirebaseAnalytics;`
`mFirebaseAnalytics = FirebaseAnalytics.getInstance(this);`
`Bundle bundle = new Bundle();`
`bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.ITEM_ID, "1");`
`bundle.putString(FirebaseAnalytics.Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "Test");`
`mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(FirebaseAnalytics.Event.SELECT_CONTENT, bundle);`
```

Comment: session_start is one of the default events: https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485?hl=en

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie When does it occur though? It only says "when a user engages the app or website " . It's not just onCreate of the Application class or something, right?

Comment: @androiddeveloper I am not sure exactly, it appears to be a little more complex than just lifecycle callback like onCreate or onResume. I think they have a configurable session duration.

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie I see. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to disable generation of the event by setting the minimum session duration to a very large number: [FirebaseAnalytics.setMinimumSessionDuration()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/analytics/FirebaseAnalytics.html#setMinimumSessionDuration(long)).